# Unexpected import token - testing React Native with Jest

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jestjs

I'm getting a weird import error when I try to test my react-native app with jest. I have babel-jest, babel-preset-react-native, jest, jest-react-native and react-test-render all installed but get this error message when I run npm test.

● Test suite failed to run

```
/Users/maftalion/www/stars20/kiosk/node_modules/native-base/index.js:4
import Drawer from './Components/vendor/react-native-drawer';
^^^^^^
**SyntaxError: Unexpected token import**

  at transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/transform.js:316:10)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/routes/Identification.js:3:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/routes/router.js:4:21)
```

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        1.011s

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out, basically throw any node modules that use es6 syntax in transformIgnorePatterns.

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
   "node_modules/(?!react-native|native-base|react-clone-referenced-element)"
],
```

Comment: More context on this workaround: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/396#issuecomment-270116326

Answer (score 2):

Try adding [`transformIgnorePatterns`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#transformignorepatterns-array-string) to your package.json:

```
{
  "name": "MyAwesomeApp",
  ...
  "jest": {
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["/node_modules/"]
  }
}
```

For me Jest works out of the box, however:

```
$ react-native init MyAwesomeApp
$ cd MyAwesomeApp
$ npm test
...
Tests:       2 passed
```

I'm using React Native v0.37.0.

Comment: Yea when I created a new RN app jest worked fine too, don't know why its giving me issues.

transformIgnorePatterns makes both my tests fail

Comment: Setting it to "/node_modules/" will not work, as it instructs Jest to not transpile all 3rd party libraries. This is also the default config value, so it's not really changing anything.

See https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#transformignorepatterns-array-string

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers given earlier didn't solve `Unexpected token import` errors *in the tests itself*, if they are written in ES6 (like the boilerplate tests created by the [Ignite CLI](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite) after `ignite new MyProject`).

I finally managed to remove ES6-related errors by adding to the `test` task in `package.json`:

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --no-cache"
```

I am using RN `0.45.1`, Node `7.10.1` (and `8.1.2`), Yarn `0.24.6` and Jest `20.0.4`

PS: Don't always see this in the console, but in VS Code `v1.13.1` setting `--no-cache` makes the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You configured Babel in your [webpack config](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tomatchsnapshotoptionalstring) and this will only apply to webpack. When other tools, like Jest, use Babel, they won't see that configuration because they don't look at the webpack config. You can use a .babelrc file to configure Babel and that will apply to anything that runs Babel (not just webpack).

Using a .[babelrc](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/) is usually preferred as you want to have a general babel config, and if you need to override a setting, you can still do that in the specific application like in the webpack config.

Create the following .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

With that, you can remove the presets option in your webpack config because it will use the .babelrc. Note that the [cacheDirectory option][3] is specific to babel-loader and is not used to configure the underlying Babel.

You also have a typo in your test, [toMatchSnapShot()](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tomatchsnapshotoptionalstring) should be toMatchSnapshot().

```
expect(rendered.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add .babelrc with:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/env","@babel/react"]
}
```

I also needed to install this module
`npm install add --dev react-test-renderer`