# Jest ES6 Error unexpected token import?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, babel-jest

Hello how can I use ES6 with Jest. Because they send me a mistake in spread (operator) and export.
How to modify jest?

```js
export default function reducer(state={
    open:false
  }, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
      case "HANDLE_TAP_HOME": {
        return {...state,open:action.open}
        
      }
    }

    return state
}
```

test

```js
import base from '../../client/src/redux/reducer/reducers/Admin/base/Index'

describe('request to Reducer',()=>{
    it('fetch',()=>{
        expect(base(undefiend,{type:'nothing'})).toEqual({
            open:false
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: There is no spread operator in the code you've posted.

Comment: What is the error you are getting here?

Comment: Unexpected token import

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: [Unexpected import token - testing React Native with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45058308/8295283)

Comment: Yes, using the spread syntax with objects in ES6 is a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jest configuration file

```js
"jest": {
    "scriptPreprocessor": "<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-babel-preprocessor/preprocessor.js",
    "unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/react"
    ]
  }
```

dependencies

**npm i --D jest-cli jest-babel-preprocessor**

bye